# Which paragraph in the C++ Standard prohibits the conversion of a pointer-to-const into a pointer-to-non-const?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

Which paragraph in the C++ Standard prohibits the conversion from a `const char*` argument into a `char*` parameter? I know this is correct. I just would like to know where this is stated in the Standard?

```
#include <iostream>

std::string message("Hello");

void my_log(char* pchar) {
    std::cout << pchar << '\n';
}


void my_func(const std::string& message)
{
    my_log(const_cast<char*>((&message)->c_str()));     // Ok
    my_log((&message)->c_str());                        // Doesn't compile
}


int main() {
    my_func(message);
}
```

See live example [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/dbe4cbbf7f1141ae).

Comment: `(&foo)->bar()` is usually just written as `foo.bar()`.

Comment: Why don't you fix `my_log` to take a `const char*`?

Comment: Because to have a contrived example to demonstrate a trivial problem there often need to be contrivances.

Comment: Side note: If you have a Standard revision in mind you should add it. Otherwise, you'll likely get most-recent.

Comment: @user4581301 The most recent is fine.

Comment: https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/conv.qual

Comment: @NathanOliver Context clues tell me you found the right paragraph, but the content of the paragraph seem undecipherable to me.

Comment: There is no paragraph which explicitly prohibits, there just none which allows. But there is a paragraph which explicitly says that the program is ill-formed due to initialization which would need a non-existent conversion: https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/dcl.init#17.9 (namely, https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/dcl.init#17.9.sentence-3)

Comment: @LanguageLawyer Sentence 3 in paragraph 17.9 says: "If the conversion cannot be done, the initialization is ill-formed." That's ok. But where does it say that the initialization is ill-formed?

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux I think it's that plus some paragraphs in [over](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/over) but those two sections almost need a PhD in standardess in order to understand them.  Unfortunately I don't have the time to try and stich it together.

Comment: _But where does it say that the initialization is ill-formed?_ WDYM?

Comment: I was hoping there would be clearer wording in C++11 and perhaps we could track the wording forward as the Standard evolved, but no such luck. Or if there is such luck I still can't find it.

Comment: @LanguageLawyer I should have said: where does it say that the conversion cannot be done?

Comment: Nowhere. You just can't find one which can do it.

Comment: *Qualification-combined type* of `char*` and `const char*` is `const char*`. Then per [**\[conv.qual\]/3**](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/conv.qual#3) "A prvalue of type `T1` can be converted to type `T2` if the qualification-combined type of `T1` and `T2` is `T2`". `char*` can be converted to `const char*`. This paragraph doesn't permit conversion from `const char*` to `char*`; nor does any other. The standard exhaustively lists all conversions that are allowed; it doesn't list all conversions that are disallowed. E.g. it doesn't explicitly say that `int` can't convert to `char*`.